# java.net.UnknownHostException: <CLUSTER_NAME>on HA cluster while connecting hive from local machine

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, cloudera

I tried to connect hadoop cluster from my local machine but getting the following given below error

```
[ashsshar@slc01nwj work]$ hive --config /<hive_conf_file_location>/conf -S -f /<hive_scirpt>
 1 2.0.0-cdh4.2.0 
FAILED: IllegalArgumentException java.net.UnknownHostException: <cluster_name>
[ashsshar@slc01nwj work]$
```

I also tried executing the same hive script on hadoop cluster that worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

UnknownHostException means that the hostname resolution is not happening from your local machine. Check if you can ping to your cluster with it's hostname